# How to quickly make this shape?

Tags: modeling

How to build that very quickly ? ; )

[image]

Comment: How did you make the one pictured?

Comment: try starting with an icosphere and delete the faces,parent the star to the sphere and use dupli face set on vertices. or a particle system where the number of emitted particles = number of vertices on the sphere and make it emit from the vertices.

Comment: well... the icosphere is a good start... after that 2 modifiers are needed... : )

Comment: The 2 modifiers will be Wireframe and Subsurf at 1-st level. What was the scope of the question then if you know that already ?

Comment: @MrZak well.. just because i discovered that today and i thought that can be share... no ?

Comment: The scope of the SE sites is sharing knowledge and from that point of view you'll go ahead and add answer to your question without waiting people to guess that. I'm not sure if this concrete question should be answered here though as it's hard to know where could it be applicable (except only for some specific cases).

Answer (score 4):

Yes : this is an icosphere with both (and in this order) a wireframe and a subsurf modifier.

here is the sequence :
[image]

The point is : I wanted to share the wireframe modifier possibilities as I discovered it today.

Here are some other very simple possibilities, just starting from the basic shapes:

[image]